# How to make values in a rows appear as columns based on a unique value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to get the following items to show as columns based on the check no in SQL. Please help

```
Check No    Item Name
-----------------------------------
1010000001  3/4 Time Session Ale
1010000001  Aquilani Gls
1010000001  Australian Psycho 50L
1010000001  Bloody Mary
1010000001  Brookvale Ginger Beer
1010000001  Buffalo Trace
1010000001  CafÃ© Latte
1010000001  Cake Sparkling Gls
1010000001  Cap
1010000001  Capi Blood Orange
1010000001  Capi Dry Ginger
1010000002  Capi Pink Grapefruit
1010000002  Capi Soda
1010000002  Capi Sparkling Mineral
1010000002  Capi Yuzu
1010000002  Cappucino
1010000002  Carlton Draught
1010000002  Catalina Sounds Gls
1010000002  Chicken Taco
1010000002  Chivas Regal 12 Yr
1010000002  Coke
1010000002  Corona
```

Expected Result:

```
Check No   Item Name
---------------------------------------------------
1010000001 3/4 Time Session Ale Aquilani Gls Australian Psycho 50L etc...
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ... ?

Comment: @Arulkumar SQL server

Comment: Which version? SQL Server 2008, 2012, ... ?

Comment: @Arulkumar 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return your expected result:

```
SELECT [Check No], 
       Items = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Item Name]
                      FROM TableName AS T1
                      WHERE T1.[Check No] = T2.[Check No]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM TableName AS T2
GROUP BY [Check No];
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Any possibility you can help me to add a comma next to each item name? this is for a market basket analysis.

Comment: Yes, instead of `SELECT ' ' + [Item Name]` replace as `SELECT ', ' + [Item Name]` or please try the updated answer. I have edited it.

Comment: Is there a possibility of turning each item name to columns?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I need to get the results in a format where each item falls into a unique column, Example; Checkno Item name1 | Item name2 | Item name 3 etc...

Comment: @AshanMeegoda Okay, can you please post a separate question for this. So some one can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you want join the `Item name` strings when they have the same `Check No` value, so what database do you use now ? if you use PostgreSQL, you can just use the `array_agg` function to implete this, like below:

```
select
    check_no,
    array_to_string(array_agg(item_name),' ') as result
from
    your_table_name
group by
    check_no
```

Comment: I use SQL server. I got following error when I tried to execute it,Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'array_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.